# can not debug docker alphine image Visual Studio 2017 15.9.20

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug alphine based aspnet core 2.1   docker image with visual studio Visual Studio 2017 15.9.20 .

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-alpine AS base
```

When i start the debugger in visual studio it builds the project and exist.Debugger is not attached.
But when i tried    `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS base` it works as expected (debugger is attached.)
How can i attach the debugger to alpine based image.